# PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven

I have problem and I need help

```java
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named JSFCrudPU
```

My persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="JSFCrudPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsfcruddb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="prezes123123"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Do you have Hibernate on the classpath?

Comment: If you ask about lib to Hibernete a have all in pom.xml  And this is my class where i use this        private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JSFCrudPU");
 private EntityManager em;

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml as well?

Comment: give me email and i send you all my project

Comment: it would probably be best to upload it to some sharing service for everyone to be able to check